# How to insert data into table in hive using INSERT INTO tblnm VALUES(value1,value2....)

Tags: hadoop, hive, insert-into

I am trying to insert data into hive table.but it is giving error.please help.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy as we insert data in RDBMS tables.let say I have one test_table in hive:-

> hive> desc test_table;
>
> OK
>
> col1  string
>
> col2  string
>
> Time taken: 0.056 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
>
> hive>**insert into table test_table values ('10','100');**

It will run a map-reduce job.Once that is completed.You can see the data by running select *

> hive> select * from test_table;
>
> OK
>
> 10      100
>
> Time taken: 0.209 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)